# Can gulp completely replace grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

Recently I'm looking into gulp, I like its idea of stream and using code to build tasks.

I used to use grunt for development workflow, now I want to use gulp to replace grunt.

But grunt seems to be more than a build tool, it marked itself task runner. Gulp, instead, focuses on build. My question is: can gulp completely replace grunt for everything? Or it should be only one part of grunt, only for build?
(Please don't consider how many plugins existing for both tools. Just think about it from function point view, can gulp cover all functionality that grunt provides? )

Answer (score 1):

No not yet. Gulp still needs time to mature to have all of the functionally possible with grunt and its third party modules.`*`

`*` source: http://markdalgleish.github.io/presentation-build-wars-gulp-vs-grunt/#39

On a personal note, I believe it will eclipse grunt sooner than later.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly haven't delved too deep into either tool, but from what I've seen gulp can do just about anything grunt can.